# Google Map SDK integration without using url scheme

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-api-3

Hello I'm looking for googleMaps without installing `Google Map` in the Device. Plotting places within my iOS App.

Can Anybody suggest ?

Thanks

Comment: Asking for resource is offtopic and also a very simple Google search would have let you to this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/

Comment: Google Sdk wants us to download googleMaps app to the device,,,I am asking is there any way to access Google Sdk without installing GoogleMaps App

Comment: I does not require the Google Map Apps, you can use the SDK without the Google Maps app.

Comment: If i want to get directions between places ..it requires googleApp to be installed

Comment: You could draw the route yourself on a Google (or Apple) map view in your app. You just need access to the route API. But asking for this is offtopic.

Comment: Just use the Google Maps Directions API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/